# How do I remove ['']?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'https://www.benzinga.com/premarket/'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
df = tables[5]
firstProductSet = df.iloc[: , [0]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(firstProductSet)
# print(df1)


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url = "https://thestockmarketwatch.com/markets/after-hours/trading.aspx"
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
SecondProductSet = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'symbol'})
secondProductSet =  SecondProductSet[0:15]
driver.quit()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(secondProductSet)
# print (df2)


df3 = set(df1["Stock"]).intersection(set(df2[0]))
# df4 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df4 = str(df3)
df5 = df4.replace('"',"")

# df5 = pd.DataFrame(df4.iloc[0].values)
# df6 = df5.replace(r'["]0\n0 ','')
# print(df6)




url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + df5
```

I'm using selenium and inserting this value above (FTFT). The URL doesn't work if there is an extra ['']. Any help would help me so much. This is a small part of the code but I hope it makes my question more clear.

Comment: I see you create a string. Quick and dirty you can use `df4.replace('"',"")` to remove the quotes

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on. Please consider posting a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AntonvanderWel I aslo tried that, but it doesnt work, I printed the url out : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{'FTFT'}  . Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: Sorry that is not clear for me

Comment: the current output is: finance.yahoo.com/quote/{'FTFT'}, my goal is to get this finance.yahoo.com/quote/FTFT

Comment: We understand that, but it's very unclear what your code is doing, because it is so incomplete. Please post the complete code.

Comment: @Robson i posted part of the full code

Comment: That's great. So to confirm, you are able to successfully run that code, but the problem is that `url` is equal to `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{'FTFT'}` when it finishes running?

Comment: yes correct, i only want finance.yahoo.com/quote/FTFT

Comment: Good stuff - I'll post a suggested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My understanding:* You are able to successfully run the code, but the problem is that the `url` is equal to `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{'FTFT'}` and not `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FTFT` at the end.

A potential solution to this would be to ignore all the `df4` and `df5` stuff and use `df3` like this:

```py
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + ''.join(df3)
print (url)
```

That will combine all the items in df3 into one string, which in our case is fine, because there's only one item in there. So the end result of that would be `FTFT`. When combined with the rest of the url the answer would be `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FTFT`.

For a more robust solution, I would suggest looping round the items in df3 and then processing each item. If that's what you want to do.